# How to expand/collapse on partial title when using the semantic-ui-react accordion

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I have an accordion title that consists of the carat, some text, and a div with some other stuff.  I want the accordion to only expand when the user clicks the carat or the text, but not the extra div.  Clicking on the div will do something else entirely.

I noticed that in the base Semantic-UI, you can specify a CSS selector to trigger on, but that seems JQuery specific and not doable in the react version.

Is this possible?

```
<Accordion.Title
   active={activeIndex === 0} index={0} onClick={this.handleClick}
>
  <Icon name="dropdown" />
  <span className="name">{data.name}</span>
  <div>some extra junk - don't expand on this</div>
</Accordion.Title>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onClick event is attached to the `Accordion.Title` itself. That means when you click that component, your handleClick function will fire. If you want the handleClick function to fire when clicking the `Icon` then you need to move your handler function to that component instead.

```
<Icon 
  name='dropdown'
  onClick={this.handleClick}
/>
```